# PHP/XPath - Finding a string in a table and displaying the previous cell

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, xpath

I am trying to find a string in a table, if the string is found to display the previous cell.

An example of the table is below

```
<table id="mytable">
       <tr>
           <td>
               Apples
           </td>
           <td>
               ID3030
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
              Pears
           </td>
           <td>
              ID3040
           </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

I would like it to search for ID3040 and return the string Pears (the previous cell to ID3040).

I am trying to do this through php/xpath but cannot properly figure it out.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($res);

$table = $dom->getElementById('mytable');

if(!$table) { 
    die("Table not found!");
} 

echo $table->C14N();
```

Just pulling the table and displaying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath expression to find a `<td>` that contains the string you're searching for:

```
tr/td[contains(., "ID3040")]
```

Then, you need to slide back to the `<td>` preceding it:

```
tr/td[contains(, "ID3040")]/preceding-sibling::td
```

Then, you anchor the expression by passing in `$table` as the context:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$res = $xpath->query('...', $table);
```

Comment: Yeah that works perfectly! I'll have to do some more research on xpath and DOM elements. Very powerful stuff

Comment: @jaymorgan XPath 1 is what PHP supports, version 2 is even more powerful :)